# Android: Mediaplayer stop / start playing raw resource

Tags: android, media-player, playback

It now plays on first press, stops on second press or press of another sound button. If I let a sound play through I can restart it or play another sound on a single press.

My goal is for the second press of the same button to stop it, but the press of a new button to just start the new sound instead of first press of new button stopping the old sound, second press starting the new sound.

I can see why it does what it does now but am not sure how to make it work the way I want.

```
public void playSound(int input){
    if (mp!=null && mp.isPlaying()) {
         mp.stop();
         mp.reset();
    } else{
         if (mp!=null){
             mp.reset();
             mp.release();
         }
         mp = MediaPlayer.create(Soundboard.this, input);
         mp.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Edit that. It will play the sound all the way through and then there is a couple second wait beyond the end before the button will function again. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I have gotten it to function differently as described above but am short of my goal. If you can shed any more light on this I would appreciate it. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

This block of code:

```
if (mp!=null){
    mp.reset();
    mp.release();
}
```

will never be executed.  `mp` can only be `null` at this point, as it is in the `else` block of an `if (mp != null)` test.  This suggests that there is a flaw in your thinking regarding the use of this method.

If a sound has played through and you press the button, then this code will execute:

```
mp.release();
mp = null;
```

Since `mp` was not `null`, the `else` block doesn't execute and no new sound is played.  When the button is pressed a second time, `mp` is now `null` and the `else` block gets executed, creating a new `MediaPlayer` and playing the sound.