# Android: Avoid duplicate media from being played. stop(), start()

Tags: android, onclick, media-player

This has got to be simple.  I have a single button in my app.  When you press the button it plays a sound that's about 1 minute long.  The problem is that if someone presses the button twice, three times, etc...the sounds will just build on each other.  How do I prevent a second sound from being played.  Here is the onClick code.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        final MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer=MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), R.raw.ifightsong);  
        mMediaPlayer.reset();
        mMediaPlayer.start();

    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MediaPlayer.isPlaying()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#isPlaying%28%29)
May be what you want.
You can check out [MediaPlayer.isLooping()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#isLooping%28%29) as well.

Comment: Yep, found this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4812947/android-problem-with-mediaplayer-stop-start-playing-raw-resource